# Is it possible to use 2 bars "|" as delimiter for Javascript and Java?

Tags: java, javascript, tokenize, delimiter

I have a string:

```
var metadata = "form=string=a||list=string=a|b|c||isTrue=boolean=true";
```

I want to trim it as:

```
meta[0] = "form=string=a";
meta[1] = "list=string=a|b|c";
meta[2] = "isTrue=boolean=true";
```

How can I do it in both Javascript and Java?

Comment: In Java, you need `metadata.split("\\|\\|");`.  I won't write an answer because I don't know for sure whether this works in Javascript too.  I think for Javascript, you have to write `metadata.split(/\|\|/);` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `split()` function in javascript and java

eg:

**In javascript**

```
var metadata = "form=string=a||list=string=a|b|c||isTrue=boolean=true";

var meta = metadata.split("||");
console.log(meta[0]);
```

**In java**

```
String metadata = "form=string=a||list=string=a|b|c||isTrue=boolean=true";
String[] meta = metadata.split("\\|\\|");
System.out.println( meta[0] );
```

Comment: The JS answer is correct... can be tested via a browser's console easily enough.